# How to convert base64 image to html input file tags?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0K
save to 
html

I need to get the file(file[0]) value and Ajax to submit to the PHP.

I don't want to convert the file in PHP,THANK YOU!

Comment: Can you describe your problem better? You want to upload image which you have as base64 string? From where you get this image?

Comment: Your question is unclear. If you want to strip off the file-info then do `'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0K'.split(',')[1]`. Using AJAX is a well-traveled path -- if you need that knowledge too then a quick search will give you that knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

THANK YOU!I have to solve this problem!

```
var imageUrl = signaturePad.toDataURL(); //GET data:image/png;base64 
var file = new mOxie.File(null, imageUrl);
file.name = "logsimage.jpg";
```